# Swift Permutation Algorithm Backtracking

Tags: swift, algorithm

Can anyone explain me the backtracking algorithm? I'm trying to make a permutation program for example if n=2, program will print

```
1,2
2,1
```

Although I did this in high-school the teacher didn't really care about us hard enough for us to understand it and I didn't really understand it, neither the algorithms on the internet.

This is what I did so far in the playground but I find myself stuck. I get

`1
0
1
0`

```
import Foundation

let n = 2
var tempMatrix : [Int] = []
var resultString : String = ""

//1,2 || 2,1
//0,0

func initTempMatrix(){
    for _ in 0..<n {
        tempMatrix.append(0)
    }
}

func resetMatrixValue(val: Int) {
    tempMatrix[val] = 0
}

func isSolution() -> Bool {
    for i in 0..<n-1 {
        if tempMatrix[i] == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func isValid() -> Bool {
    for i in 0..<n-1 {
        if tempMatrix[n-1] == tempMatrix[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func increaseMatrix(val: Int) -> Bool {
    if tempMatrix[val] < n {
        tempMatrix[val] += 1
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func backtrack() {
    initTempMatrix()

    var k = 1
    while k != 0 {
        while !isSolution() {
            if increaseMatrix(val: k-1) {
                k+=1
            }
        }

        if isValid() {
            for i in 0..<tempMatrix.count {
                resultString += "\(tempMatrix[i])"
                print(resultString)
                resultString = ""
            }
        }

        resetMatrixValue(val: k-1)
        k -= 1
    }
}

backtrack()
```

Comment: Can you provide more samples, like n=0, n=1, n=3.

Comment: n = 3: `1
1
0
1
1
0
2
1
0
2
1
0
3
1
0
3
1
0
`

each character on one row